# How can I fix an issue which causes players to die upon joining to my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

When a player joins my server, he automatically dies and it repeats, over and over and over. How can I fix this with console commands?

Comment: Is the repeated death caused by something you/a friend has set up with command blocks?

Comment: I didn't set it up, neither did a friend, but someone got on the server with hacks and somehow did this. If there is a command block, how would I fix it? No one can join the server without dying.

Comment: You could reset the world, or enable god-mode on a player in a single-player game to find out what's going on. Does the console read anything?

Comment: I'll try the god mode idea.

Comment: 28.08 14:54:51 [Server] INFO [@: Killed Absinthial]
28.08 14:54:51 [Server] INFO [@: Killed Absinthial]
28.08 14:54:51 [Multicraft] Absinthial ran command Message of the Day
28.08 14:54:51 [Connect] User Absinthial- This goes on and on and on in console...

Comment: Try going into your server.properties and turn command blocks off. If you look back into the logs for when the death started you should be able to find who was online when the command block was placed.

Comment: Someone made a command block clock killing you constantly :\

Answer (score 1):

There is a repeating unnamed command block in your world, set to kill all players. You have to go into your server.properties and turn command blocks off until you can find the repeating command block and turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

After doing what Isaac said, I'd also recommend using the `fill` command to get rid of the command block. Ex: `/fill [X1] [Y1] [Z1] [X2] [Y2] [Z2] command_block air replace`

where the parameters in brackets are world coordinates from bottom left corner to top right. Make the region big enough to get the block within a reasonable radius of spawn,but not too big because you don't want it to lag out.